# Prove that $P(x)-x$ divides $ P(P(P(x))) − x $

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

> Prove that for any polynomial $ P(x) $ with real coefficients, other than polynomial $x$, the polynomial $ P(P(P(x))) − x $ is divisible by $ P(x) − x $.

Since we have $a-b\mid P(a)-P(b)$ for each $a,b$, we have also $$P(x)-x\mid P(P(x))-P(x)$$ and thus $$P(x)-x\mid (P(P(x))-P(x))+ (P(x)-x)$$

so $$P(x)-x\mid P(P(x))-x\mid P(P(P(x)))-P(x)$$

and thus $$P(x)-x\mid (P(P(P(x)))-P(x))+ (P(x)-x)$$

and finaly we have $$P(x)-x\mid P(P(P(x)))-x$$

*I'm not satisfied with the lenght of the proof. Any shorter way?*

Comment: This is a perfectly fine and reasonably short proof. You're not going to be able to optimize the proof length much more than this.

Comment: It seems to me that proving that $P(x)-x\mid P^{n}(x)-x$ for all $n\geq 1$ by induction might be a little shorter : what you've done here is basically proving that it holds trivially for $1$, hence for $2$, hence for $3$, so in an induction proof the two "hence" would be done in one step.

Comment: @Cardioid_Ass_22 Actually we can shorten it and - moreover - make it clearer intuitively - see below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, $\bmod P(x)\!-\!x\!:\ \color{#c00}{P(x)\equiv x}\,$ so $\,P(P(\color{#c00}{P(x)}))\equiv P(P(\color{#c00}{x}))\equiv P(x)\equiv x\ $

We iteratively applied the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) thrice to replace $\,P(x)\,$ by the congruent $\,x\,$ (the linked proof of the rule is given for integers but works in any commutative ring since it uses only ring axioms). An obvious induction extends this to $\,P^n(x)\equiv x\,$ for all $\,n\ge 0\,$ yielding

**Corollary** $\ P(x)\!-\!x\,$ divides $\, P^n(x)\!-\!x\,$ for all $\,n\in\Bbb N,\,$ and all polynomials $\,P(x)$

Hence - from a modular perspective - we can view it as a special case of the obvious

- [fixed points stay fixed under iteration](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3167836/242), which has an obvious inductive step,

$\quad\ $ namely: $\, $ if $\ \color{#c00}{f(x) = x}\ $ then $\, {f^{\large n}(x) = x}\,\Rightarrow\, f^{\large n+1}(x) = f^n(\color{#c00}{f(x)})=f^n(\color{#c00}x)=x$

As usual, modular arithmetic simplifies the matter by replacing divisibility *relations* by more intuitive arithmetic (ring) *operations*, enabling us to appeal to our well-honed *algebraic* (ring) intuition from common number systems.

Comment: Thank you Bill!