# On $a_n=3^{a_{n-1}}$ with $a_1=3$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Define
$$a_n=3^{a_{n-1}}$$
for $n\ge 2$ with $a_1=3$. I observed that
$$a_{11}=\ldots 2464195387,$$
$$a_{12}=\ldots 2464195387,$$
$$a_{13}=\ldots 2464195387$$
and this seems to hold as we continue increasing the index of $a$. I.e. the last decimal digits seem to be the same for all $a_n$ with $n\ge 11$.

How is this even possible? Can someone explain this? I'm familiar with Euler's theorem in number theory.

You can check the results with e.g. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=3%5E3%5E3%5E3%5E3%5E3%5E3%5E3%5E3%5E3%5E3%5E3

Comment: Because $\,3^a \equiv a\pmod{\!10^{10}}\,$ for $\,a = 2464195387.\,$ Similar matters are discussed in prior questions.

Comment: @BillDubuque How did you find this identity?

Comment: Here is a related question with some explanations: [Do the last digits of exponential towers really converge to a fixed sequence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159995/do-the-last-digits-of-exponential-towers-really-converge-to-a-fixed-sequence).

Comment: $a_{n+1} \equiv a_n\!\iff 3^{a_n} \equiv a_n.\,$ If so then by $\rm\color{#c00}{induction}$ $\,a_{n+k} \equiv a_n\,$ for all $k\ge 0,\,$ i.e. $\,a_{n+k} = 3^{\large \color{#c00}{a_{n+k-1}}}\! \equiv 3^{\large\color{#c00}{a_n}}\! \equiv a_n,\,$ i.e. [fixed points stay fixed upon iteration](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3167836/242) $\,f(a_n) \equiv a_n \Rightarrow f^k(a_n) \equiv a_n\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I meant how did you find $3^{2464195387}\equiv 2464195387\mod 10^{10}$?

Comment: As I explained in my prior comment, that follows immediately from your equations, i.e. from the fact that $\,a_{12}\,$ and $\,a_{11}\,$ have the same last $10$ digits, i.e. $\,a_{12}\equiv a_{11}\pmod{\!10^{10}}\\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque I know, but I would like to know how "my results" can be proved without WolframAlpha.

Comment: Here's why: $\,a\equiv b\pmod{\!10^{k-1}}\Rightarrow 3^a\equiv 3^b\pmod{\!10^{k}}\,$ for $k>2,\,$ by ${\rm lcm}(\phi(2^k),\phi(5^k)) = 10^{k-1}.\,$ So for $\,a,b =\, a_{k+1},\,a_k$ this yields that if $\,a_{k+1}\,$ and $\,a_k\,$ have the same last $k\!-\!1$ digits then $\,a_{k+2}\,$ and $\,a_{k+1}\,$ have the same last $\,k\,$ digits, so we get one more agreeing digit for each increment of $\,k.\ \ $

Comment: $$\begin{align}
{\rm e.g.}\ \ \ 3\!\uparrow\uparrow\!4 \equiv 3\!\uparrow\uparrow\!3 &\equiv\ \  87\! \pmod{\!10^2}\\[.3em]
\Rightarrow\ \ \ 3^{3\uparrow\uparrow 4}\ \equiv\ 3^{3\uparrow\uparrow3}\ &\equiv\ \ 3^{87}\!\!\!\pmod{\!10^3}\\[.3em]
{\rm i.e.}\ \ \ 3\!\uparrow\uparrow\!5 \equiv 3\!\uparrow\uparrow\!4 &\equiv 387 \!\!\pmod{\!10^3}\\
 \end{align}\qquad\qquad$$